# Convexity and NP-hardness

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, np-complete

Suppose that we have the following optimization problem:

$$Maximize_{x_{j,i}} ~ {{\sum_t \sum_i \sum_j (a_{0,i;t}+\sum_i \sum_j a_{j,i;t} x_{j,i;t})}\over{\sum_t\sum_i\sum_j x_{j,j;t} b_{j,i;t}}}$$

$$s.t. ~\sum_t\sum_i\sum_j x_{j,j;t} b_{j,i;t} \leq C, ~~~C\in R_{>0}$$

In the combinatorial scenario where it holds that $x\in {\{0,1\}}$, it can be shown that the solution space increases exponentially with $t, i, j$, and that the time-complexity of an exhaustive search would be of the scale $O(k^n)$. I'm under the impression that, had this been a linear problem where convexity is guaranteed, NP-hardness would not be an issue and one could have solved the problem efficiently (correct me if I'm wrong here). But the non-linearity cases confuses me. I understand that a problem can be [both convex and NP-hard](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92939/can-all-convex-optimization-problems-be-solved-in-polynomial-time-using-interior), though I'm not sure that what that implies in practice.

My questions:

1. What ways are there to prove convexity in this problem?
2. Is there a point in trying to prove convexity? Does convexity supersede NP-hardness or is that a false impression of mine?

Comment: What is the value of the objective function if all $x_{j,j;t}$ are $0$? The relaxed problem (with $0\leq x_{j,j;t}$ \leq 1$ seems quasiconvex and efficiently solvable as a fractional optimization problem.

Comment: The value of the objective would then be equal to $\infty$ so that would not be a feasible solution, thanks for pointing out that extra constraint.

Comment: @LinAlg What you're suggesting sounds very interesting. If I obtain an optimal solution on the relaxed quasiconvex problem, would it make sense to round up its values to obtain a solution compatible to the original problem? And would that back-transformed optimal solution obtained from the relaxed problem be any close to the actual optimal solution of the original problem?

Comment: The relaxed problem is unbounded (the objective can get arbitrarily close to $\infty$), so you need to add a constraint that the sum of $x$ should be at least $1$. Rounding $x$ is often not a good strategy, look at branch&bound.

Comment: @LinAlg - thank you for this idea. Feel free to turn your comments into an answer so that I can vote for best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be summarized as
$$\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} \left\{ \frac{a^Tx + b}{d^Tx} : 1 \leq d^Tx \leq C \right\}.$$
You can solve the relaxed problem ($0 \leq x_i \leq 1$) and round the solution to get a binary solution, but then you lose optimality. You could do branch & bound on the fractional solution, but that is a bit hard to implement because the relaxed problem needs to be reformulated before it can be solved. Below I explain an easier way to feed this problem into mixed integer optimization software such as CPLEX or Gurobi by making it linear.

You can reformulate the problem as:
$$\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^n, y \geq 1} \left\{ (a^Tx + b)y : 1 \leq y \leq C, (d^Tx)y = 1\right\}.$$
This is not linear yet, but you can recognize the product of a binary and a continuous variable. Adding $z_i = x_i y$ and McCormick envelopes you get an equivalent linear formulation:
$$\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^n, y \geq 1, z \geq 0} \left\{ a^Tz + by : 1 \leq y \leq C, d^Tz = 1, z_i \leq x_i C, z_i \geq y - C(1-x_i) \right\}.$$